# How to read coordinate from the DB and map a pointer on the map using django

Tags: python, django, folium

As a newbie with python, I am thinking of doing a project, where I have a table of e.g shops, with their names, longitude, latitude, and shop manager.

I want to design a django project where the coordinates (longitude, latitude) will be used to place a pointer on the map to indicate the location on the map, and if hovered, it will show the shop details. I can go as far as if clicked on, the will display the shop page with details, etc.

Answer (score 0):

DONE :)

I used the import_export import resource module to bring it to the frontend and the Tablib.export() module to convert it to DataFrame.